# Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules

Tags: angular, angular14

I want to use [ngx-avatar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-avatar) in angular standalone component v14.

I use it in the template and I was imported it in the component imports.

But I got error message:

```
Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pmups5?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
import { AvatarModule } from 'ngx-avatar';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AvatarModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    app works!

    <ngx-avatar class="my-avatar" value="HM"> </ngx-avatar>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
}
```

I try to solve it using `importProvidersFrom` but it's not work:

```
bootstrapApplication(
  AppComponent, {
   providers: [importProvidersFrom(AvatarModule.forRoot())],
  }
);
```

Any idea how I can make it work?

Comment: If it is not a standalone component, I believe it has to be imported in a module.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve this problem, importing a "SharedModule" with the dependencies you need, later if you need to add stuff, you can do it from this module.

The code of SharedModule, could be:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AvatarModule } from 'ngx-avatar';
@NgModule({
  exports: [AvatarModule],
  imports: [HttpClientModule, AvatarModule],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Finally you just have to import the SharedModule
It works for me

Answer (score 0):

From what I found while having a [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75047548/884123), it seems like the module is malformed.

I'd would guess that the module needs to be compiled with Angular 14+ to be imported as standalone. `ngx-avatar` isn't since it hasn't been updated for over 2 years.