# Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules while importing an NgModule

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

I'm trying to import an NgModule into a standalone component but the compiler is throwing the error NG2012 : `Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.`

```
NgModule({
  declarations: [FooComponent],
  exports: [FooComponent],
});
export class FooModule {}

let comps = [ImageComponent, HighlightDirective];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FooModule],
  template: ``,
})
export class ExampleStandaloneComponent {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I lost over 30 minutes, on this.

The `NgModule` is malformed : `NgModule` should have been `@NgModule`.